# Swagger - Extract all APIs in the deployed war file

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I want to extract all the APIs in the deployed war file of my Spring-boot project.  is there a way to programatically get all API names (RequestMapping) in the war file using swagger or some other framework?

Comment: please read this documentation [monitor endpoints](https://josepraveen.com/2016/09/17/monitor-your-built-in-endpoints-spring-boot-lab-2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spring actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) in yor project. It has an end point(**/mappings**) for that.